# Name of a "mathematical declaration"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, mathematics

I'm looking for a single word that essentially means: "mathematically formal declaration." Here, declaration is in the ordinary sense of the word; i.e a declarative sentence.

The word **theorem** will not do; a theorem must have a proof. Similarly, the words **lemma, result** don't work either.

The word **conjecture** will not do; a conjecture carries the connotation that *no proof of the assertion has been found yet*.

What I want is a word that just means the assertion, without any connotation of whether a proof for it exists or not.

Comment: Are you intending any connotations as to the truth of falsehood of the statement?  If not, then _hypothesis_ could work.  (It's not specific to mathematics but it fits.)

Comment: @JDM-GBG No connotations of truth or falsehood. However, hypothesis is not generally a word used in mathematics; it typically is reserved for scientific fields. It denotes some expected observation about the physical world, whereas mathematics has nothing to do with the physical world. The mathematical analogue of 'hypothesis' would in fact be 'conjecture.'

Comment: Probably _assert_ is the communicative verb you want, and its nominalization _assertion_ has already got a metamathematical existence in the form of the `Assertion` mark, **⊦** , Unicode U+22A6, UTF-8 E2 8A A6. This is a notational part of several kinds of logics and metalogics, including Whitehead and Russell's _Principia_. See Bochenski (in bibliography [of this article](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-LogicalNotation.pdf)) for more details.

Comment: What's wrong with "theory"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word usually used by mathematicians is *statement*.

You can see this by looking at Wikipedia's entry for [Gödel's incompleteness theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems)
It says

> For any such formal system, there will always be statements about the natural numbers that are true, but that are unprovable within the system.

So here the word *statement* is used for mathematical assertions.

Outside of logic, the word isn't used anywhere near as much as *theorem* or *conjecture*, because usually mathematicians know whether a statement they're talking about has been proven (in which case they use the word *theorem*) or not (in which case they use the word *conjecture*).

Answer (score 1):

**Definition**, according to [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/definition):

> An exact statement or description of the nature, scope, or meaning of something.

Another related term in mathematics is **axiom**. According to [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/axiom) an axiom in mathematics is:

> A statement or proposition on which an abstractly defined structure is based.

Example sentence from the same source:

> ‘The second chapter presents a development of absolute and Euclidean geometry based on Hilbert's axioms.’

Both axioms and definitions are widely used in mathematics, however, not interchangeably. Definitions define something, for example a specific set of numbers. Axioms, on the other hand, are like theorems, except that they don't have a proof and don't require proof. Axioms are assumed to be true and can be used to prove other things, for example the [axiom of infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity).

Attribution:

"Definition | Definition of Definition in English by Oxford Dictionaries." Oxford Dictionaries | English. Accessed May 28, 2018. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/definition.

"Axiom | Definition of Axiom in English by Oxford Dictionaries." Oxford Dictionaries | English. Accessed May 28, 2018. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/axiom.